# python cassandra get big result of select * in generator (without storage result in ram)

Tags: python, cassandra

I want to get all data in cassandra table "user"

i have 840000 users and i don't want to get all users in python list.
i want get users in packs of 100 users

in cassandra doc https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/query_paging.html
i see i can use fetch_size, but in my python code i have database object that contains all cql instruction

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.query import SimpleStatement

class Database:
   def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.cluster = Cluster(['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2'])
        self.session = cluster.connect()

   def get_users(self):
        users_list = []
        query = "SELECT * FROM users"
        statement = SimpleStatement(query, fetch_size=10)
        for user_row in session.execute(statement):
            users_list.append(user_row.name)
        return users_list
```

actually get_users return very big list of user name
but i want to transform return get_users to a "generator"

i don't want get all users name in 1 list and 1 call of function get_users, but i want to have lot of call get_users and return list with only 100 users max every call function

for example :
list1 = database.get_users()
list2 = database.get_users()
...
listn = database.get_users()

list1 contains 100 first user in query
list2 contains 100 "second" users in query
listn contains the latest elements in query (<=100)

is this possible ?
thanks for advance for your answer

Answer (score 2):

According to [Paging Large Queries](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/query_paging.html):

> Whenever there are no more rows in the current page, the next page
>   will be fetched transparently.

So, if you execute your code like this, you will still the whole result set, but this is paged in a transparent manner.

In order to achieve what you need to use callbacks. You can also find some code sample on the link above.

I added below the full code for reference.

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.query import SimpleStatement
from threading import Event

class PagedResultHandler(object):

    def __init__(self, future):
        self.error = None
        self.finished_event = Event()
        self.future = future
        self.future.add_callbacks(
            callback=self.handle_page,
            errback=self.handle_error)

    def handle_page(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            process_row(row)

        if self.future.has_more_pages:
            self.future.start_fetching_next_page()
        else:
            self.finished_event.set()
    def handle_error(self, exc):
        self.error = exc
        self.finished_event.set()

def process_row(user_row):
    print user_row.name, user_row.age, user_row.email

cluster = Cluster()
session = cluster.connect()

query = "SELECT * FROM myschema.users"
statement = SimpleStatement(query, fetch_size=5)

future = session.execute_async(statement)
handler = PagedResultHandler(future)
handler.finished_event.wait()
if handler.error:
    raise handler.error
cluster.shutdown()
```

Moving to next page is done in `handle_page` when `start_fetching_next_page` is called.

If you replace the if statement with `self.finished_event.set()` you will see that the iteration stops after the first 5 rows as defined in `fetch_size`